# Does the rinnegan give perfect chakra control to its true wielder

Tags: naruto

Does the rinnegan give their original/true wielder perfect chakra control?

Lets say Nagato was born with his rinnegan, would he automatically have perfect control over his chakra?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "perfect control of his chakra"? Do you mean he would be able to use any jutsu or nature transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Amongst the abilities of Rinnegan, it is shown,

> One who possesses the Rinnegan can easily master any jutsu as well as all five nature transformations

Mastering any jutsu or nature transformation would only be possible with the precise chakra control. It is unclear what you're asking about, i.e. Definition of perfect. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The Rinnegan gives anyone perfect chakra control, and they also have all chakra natures. They can also revive the dead and do many other abilities that the other dojutsu can not do.